# Users cant access web part but have access to site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, permissions

I've added a clickable image to my SharePoint Online site which I can access fine. Other users who have read and limited access cant access the web part (the web part doesn't show).

Are web parts handled differently to the site contents?

Thanks

Comment: Web parts can be handled with unique permissions, but by default inherit the permissions from the page they are part of. So if this wasn't configured, it shouldn't be an issue. Instead, as you mention the wp's content to be a clickable image, is it possible the other users don't have an access to the image itself, so that the link would show up as a blank?

Comment: Is it a page that requires publishing? Have you published a major version of the page?

Comment: Is the web part has been set with target audience?